# Printing fields from json when applicable

Tags: python, json, loops

I have a json file that is generated to find the number of items available at any given time (see below). In this scenario, there are 2 items available. There are 9 of item #1 and 5 of item #2. There are 0 of all other items. However, on another day or at another time, there could be 3 or 6 or any number of items available in unknown quantities. How can I write my python to print out how many of each item there are at any given time instead of just when there are a certain number of items available?

```
{"item": [
    {
        "amount": 9
    },
    {
        "amount": 5
    }
]}
```

This is my python file. I can successfully print out when there is one item available in a variable quantity. But how can I handle a variable number of items available?

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

printItem = data["item"][0]["amount"] + ":"
print (printItem)
```

Comment: `for item in data["item"]: print(item["amount"])`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually quite simple. You just need to loop through each item and print it separately.

```py
with open(file_name) as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  items = data.item
  for item in items:
    print(item.amount)
```

This will loop every item in the `items` array from the JSON object and print each individual price.

Here's an explanation of the `for` loop. We start by defining the `for`, after which the identifier `item` declares a variable that will be set each time the loop executes. Then, `in` is used to signify that we are looping through every item `in` the object named `items`. To end the loop definition statement, we use a `:` and then indent the loop body.

Inside the loop, we can use the `item` variable as it changes for each different item in the array. The first time around, `item` will be the zeroth item the array, the second time around it will be the first, and so on. Note that after the loop is over the `item` variable will still exist. It is actually defined and can be used to reference the last value in the array, even after the loop has completed.